# Problem with pyttsx3 module not working in Visual Studio and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, text-to-speech, pyttsx

I have the following code:

```py
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

Note: I have already installed the pyttsx3 module using the command `pip install pyttsx3`

**Errors:**

**1. Visual Studio**

> ````sh
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>   File "c:/Users/Arashi__/.ipynb_checkpoints/jarvis.py", line 1, in
> <module>
>     import pyttsx3 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3' ```
> ````

**2.Jupyter notebook**
I executed the code line by line and got errors on the second line (around 100 lines of error of which, here, I show the last line for brevity sake):

> ````sh
> KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last) TypeError: item 2 in
> _argtypes_ passes a union by value, which is unsupported.** this large error ```
> ````

3.after using **engine= pyttsx3.init('dummy')** instead of the engine= pyttsx3.init() my error is resolved but  no output is generated.

How can I fix the above issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how you use pyttsx3. This program should be using `speak("Whatever goes here")` and it should say it but I suggest you look at some tutorials on how to use pyttsx3 and take some python tutorials as well. It's quite easy once you look at some examples. Something else I did with pyttsx3 is this...

```
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Use `def speak` for the easier speak function. I put this at the top of my program. On an unrelated note, you can change the gender of the voice by changing the value 0 being Male and 1 being female.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04.
Resolved by installing eSpeak:

```
    sudo apt-get install espeak
```

Before you install check and set the python version to 3 by:

```
    sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1
```

in between and after installs be sure to run:

```
    apt-get update
```

More info about this visit: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3

Hope this works for your too!

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try making a virtual environment of it and then install pyttsx3 for it

command to do so : Open terminal in vs code and type

```
python -m venv (Your file address)/venv
```